# iPhone - testing if a notification exists

Tags: iphone

At some point in a code one may add something like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doSomething) name:@"Hello" object:nil];
```

How do I test if this notification is already active on the queue or has been removed, to prevent adding a duplicate?

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid adding multiple NSNotification observer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658426/how-to-avoid-adding-multiple-nsnotification-observer)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you mean "testing for whether you've already registered as an observer for the notification", I don't think there's an easy way apart from posting the notification and seeing you get a callback (with possibly disastrous effects).

If there's a danger of a double-add, I usually use `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:foo object:bar]` before the add.

Registering for notifications does not happen on a queue.

Comment: Isn't danger to remove an observer without knowing if there's an observer to remove? Isn't like releasing an already released object? wouldn't that crash the app?

Comment: @Digital Robot; I do this all the time.  It doesn't crash.

Comment: 1. It's not like a double-release/double-free, since NSNotificationCenter does not retain the "target" or "object" (presumably it retains "name"). 2. NSNotificationCenter keeps track of (target,selector,name,object) tuples. It *must* do, because it has to know what to remove when you call removeObserver: or removeObserver:name:object:. 3. "remove" methods generally imply "don't do anything if it hasn't been added (e.g. `-[NSMutableSet removeObjectForKey:]`, `-[NSArray removeObject:]`)

Comment: Is there a race condition between the removal and the add observer where a notification could be fired and fail to trigger the observer?

Answer (score 0):

Remove observer before adding it:

[How to avoid adding multiple NSNotification observer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658426/how-to-avoid-adding-multiple-nsnotification-observer)

For unit testing you should mock NSNotificationCenter as it is dependency.