# NSNotification being added multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I have added an observer in `viewDidLoad` and the issues is if I pop back and come to the same class again, it adds observer multiple times.

Below is the code as how observer is being added:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
  {   
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"PaymentRecieved" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(PaymentRecieved:)
                                            name:@"PaymentRecieved"
                                          object:nil];
  }
```

The notification is being posted from a different view controller after some processes. Below is the code for the same:

ViewController B:

```
-(void)CardAccepted  
 {
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PaymentRecieved" object:self userInfo:nil];
 }
```

The main issue is `removeObserver` is not working. If I pop back 5 times and then push to same screen 5 times then the observer is added and fired all 5 times.

I have tried everything that was available on Stack Overflow but nothing seems to be working. Below are few of the things that I tried:

Trial 1:

```
 BOOL isPaymentObserverAdded = [DefaultsValues getBooleanValueFromUserDefaults_ForKey:@"isPaymentObserverAdded"];
 if (!isPaymentObserverAdded) {
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"PaymentRecieved" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(PaymentRecieved:)
                                            name:@"PaymentRecieved"
                                          object:nil];
  } 

 }

 [DefaultsValues setBooleanValueToUserDefaults:YES ForKey:@"isPaymentObserverAdded"];
```

Trial 2:

```
static dispatch_once_t lock;
dispatch_once(&lock, ^{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(PaymentRecieved:)
                                            name:@"PaymentRecieved"
                                          object:nil];
});
```

I know there are so many similar questions on SO for the exact same issue but none of them is solving my problem. Apart from this, I also have couple of other notifications set on this screen.

Can somone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: viewDidLoad is not called when you popBAck to the same class.

Comment: observer is added only once. Do you mean notification is being called 5 times ? Where are you calling the CardAccepted method ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri yes viewDidLoad is not called during pop back but after I pop back, I have to push again to this view to continue process. CardAccepted method is in another view controller.

Comment: it is fine that way , what do you mean by " fired all 5 times." ? Is it the notification ?

Comment: I am not sure, but  `PaymentRecieved ` method is called all 5 times, sometime 3 times, depends how many times I have pushed to the View COntroller.

Comment: I'm not sure but it *seems* that you want to do something through pushing one ViewController, but then let it only happen once. meaning if the you push the viewController a 2nd time, you don't want it to happen again. Is that right?

Comment: For this issue I always use this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/5660130/5251783 , please check it .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the observer in your viewDidLoad, you should add it to a dealloc method.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

This will remove *all* notification observers the object has subscribed to, and is good practice when using observers with pretty much all custom objects.

Comment: Deregistering in `-dealloc` has not been necessary since iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

Try to removeObserver when the user pops from the screen. Like in your back action method.

Like This :

-(void)backAction{

```
[NSNotificaitonCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"Your Notification name" object:nil]];
```

}

Comment: BTW why are you using notification center ,  you can use Custom Delegate.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Finally I did it with Custom Delegate and it is working fine now.

Comment: Glad i could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove observer on back button.sure it will work.i solved this issue just a week ago by doing this

Comment: while register notification do this.                                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"" object:dict];