# ios removing an observer before it exists raises exception

Tags: ios, objective-c

In an effort to prevent multiple observers from being added, I'm removing the observer before I add one, which was recommended here: [iPhone - testing if a notification exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799865/iphone-testing-if-a-notification-exists).

```
[[self getPlayer] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"position"];
[[self getPlayer] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"position" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

However, doing so causes an exception: `__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__`

Any ideas on how to check if an observer already exists for a key path and if so not add a new one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i tell if an object has a key value observer attached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582383/how-can-i-tell-if-an-object-has-a-key-value-observer-attached)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a boolean  that keeps track of whether or not you've added your observer. Set it to true after adding, and only remove your observer if the flag indicates that you have added one.

Comment: Yeah, that's the solution I'm using now, but wondering if there's a better practice for something like this. If not I'll stick to the bool.

Comment: Accepting this but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582383/how-can-i-tell-if-an-object-has-a-key-value-observer-attached seems to be the most appropriate solution.

Comment: Using try/catch? That's not reliable in release builds. Cocoa swallows exceptions much of the time.

Comment: anybody know if using the bool method is still the best approach?