# NSNotification - check if an observer is added before posting a notifiation

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, addobserver

my code is crashing at:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kgotNotification object:dictionary];
```

my assumption is that I am posting a notification before the observer is added.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getItems:) name:kgotNotification object:nil];
```

is there a way to check for the list of active observers before posting a notification?

Comment: You can post notifications without having an observer.  I imagine the problem with with your dictionary.

Comment: What is the error from the crash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - testing if a notification exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799865/iphone-testing-if-a-notification-exists)

Comment: Is it possible an observer has been deallocated? Have you forgotten to implement `removeObserver` in `dealloc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getItems:) name:kgotNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kgotNotification object:self userInfo:dictionary];
```

Then your getItems Method:

```
-(void)getItems:(NSNotification* )note
{
    NSLog(@"UserInfo: %@", note.userInfo);
}
```